# Open two routerLinks in the same router-outlet

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

I have three cards.

```
<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col col-4"><div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/img/aplicativo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Funções do aplicativo</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Clique aqui se deseja ver apenas as documentações para o aplicativo CondomínioApp.com.</p>
      <a routerLink="fnapp" class="btn btn-primary">Vamos lá!</a>
    </div>
</div></div><div class="col col-4">
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/img/sistema.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Funções do sistema</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Clique aqui se deseja ver apenas as documentações para o sistema CondomínioApp.com.</p>
      <a routerLink="fnweb" class="btn btn-primary">Vamos lá!</a>
    </div>
  </div></div><div class="col col-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/img/ambos.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Todas as funções</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Clique aqui se deseja ver a documentação para todas as funções do CondomínioApp.com.</p>
            <a [routerLink]="[fnapp,fnweb]" class="btn btn-primary">Vamos lá!</a>
          </div>
        </div></div></div></div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Cards #1 and #2 will open a section right below them (one or the other), and the intention is to make card #3 show the first two cards at the same time (like poorly tried with `[routerLink]="[fnapp,fnweb]"`.

I tried creating an auxiliary `router-outlet` too but it's far from the solution, since it also toggles between the two, and I can have a section showing two times.

The paths at `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ FnwebComponent, FnappComponent, AppComponent, SearchPipe ],
  imports: [ NGB_MODULES, BrowserModule, FormsModule, 
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path:'fnweb',component:FnwebComponent},
    {path:'fnapp',component:FnappComponent}
  ]), AngularFontAwesomeModule, NgbAccordionModule.forRoot(), NgbModalModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [ ],
  exports: NGB_MODULES,
  entryComponents: [ FnwebComponent, FnappComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Thanks in advance.

---

### Edit:

I've tried using outlets, but the console will always return me this: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.`. In this case, I created another component where I call both cards in the 3rd one instead of creating a function for it, as in:
`<fnapp></fnapp><fnweb></fnweb>`. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try named routing: http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

**Edit according to comment:**

**Routing config:**

```
{
path: 'card1',
component: card1,
outlet: 'card1'
}, 
{
path: 'card2',
component: card2,
outlet: 'card2'
},
```

**HTML**

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { card1: ['card1'] } }]">Card1</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { card2: ['card2'] } }]">card2</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { card1: ['card1'] }, 
    { card2: ['card2'] } }]">Card3</a>

<router-outlet name="card1"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="card2"></router-outlet>
```

I don't know exactly if this is what's you need. I did't test it so there could be so problems but it's the idea. If want to close card1 during activating routing you need to close another e.g.:

```
 outlets: { card1: null }}
```

Comment: That has the same issue auxiliary `router-outlets` have. One section will appear two times if I link it to "cardTwo"  and the user clicks on card #2 and also on "cardTwo" (not sure if I explained it clearly, but I don't think named routing is the solution).

Comment: No exactly. You can create separate naming router for card 1 and separate for card 2 and always show them inside so you will not have the same section 2 times. Then you can use funcion in card 3 to active both routers. I'll try give example asap.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I tried it but it first returned me notation errors; I had to remove the first { }'s from the routerLink (leaving it like `[outlets:{card1:['card1']}]`) and then it gave me an interpolation error, so I also had to remove the brackets from `routerLink`. Now the app opens, but returns me this in the console and doesn't show any routes: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5B%20outlets:%20%7B%20app:%20%5B'app'%5D%20%7D%20%5D'` (in this case, _app_ is the equivalent to _card1_ in your example)

Comment: But tell me if idea is good, when Yes I'll try to help you if I have free time.

Comment: It's fairly difficult for a beginner to tell what idea is good or not, but it surely made sense. However, I tried it and it gave me some issues, as mentioned. In the mean time, I used card 3's `template` to call both cards using their route tags. I'm really not sure if that's an elegant solution.